# Return object from list while looping java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Is there some straight forward way to return object from list which map to condition we passed.

Ex :

```
public enum CarType {
    TOYOTA,
    NISSAN,
    UNKNOWN;

    public static CarType getByName(String name) {
        for (CarType carType : values()) {
            if (carType.name().equals(name)) {
                return carType;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Is there some another way support by java 8 below method and for loop I have used.

```
public static CarType getByName(String name) {
    for (CarType carType : values()) {
        if (carType.name().equals(name)) {
            return carType;
        }
    }
    return UNKNOWN;
}
```

Comment: Why did you post `getByName(String)` twice ? I find it confusing.

Comment: Are you looking for the `valueOf` method that every `Enum` has?  It's not Java 8.

Comment: I would have thought that OP knew what `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase` are.

Comment: `try { return valueOf(name); } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) { return UNKNOWN; }`

Answer (score 5):

Something like this with [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) and [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) as :

```
return Arrays.stream(values())
               .filter(carType -> carType.name().equals(name))
               .findFirst().orElse(CarType.UNKNOWN);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a stream this way:

```
public static CarType getByName(String name) {
    return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(carType -> carType.name().equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(UNKNOWN);
}
```

BTW, when using IntellliJ (I am not affiliated to them ;)), it offers you an option to do this conversion automatically.

Answer (score 3):

another option

```
enum CarType {
    TOYOTA, NISSAN, UNKNOWN;

    public static CarType getByName(String name) {
        return Stream.of(CarType.values())
          .filter(x -> x.name().equals(name))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```